# How does Jake remember the events of DS9: The Visitor?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* finale “[What You Leave Behind](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind_(episode))”, a number of characters have flashbacks to defining moments over the course of the series. It’s implied (?) by the looks on their faces that they’re not just “TV flashbacks” but rather exactly what they’re remembering about their time on the station.

That being said, Jake has a series of flashbacks and one is to his father in Sick Bay following one of Ben’s reappearances in season four’s “[The Visitor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Visitor_(episode))”.

Given the ending of that episode:

> Jake helps Ben return to the moment of the accident and keep himself from dying/disappearing.

Why would Series-Finale-Jake have any memory of those events?

Comment: I can't rewatch the sequence right now, but are you sure the flashback is from *The Visitor* and not *Rapture* or some other episode?

Comment: In-universe, Jake was possessed by a time-traveling creature from another dimension. The Pah Wraith could theoretically have become aware of the alternate timeline, then theoretically could have transferred that memory to Jake when he was ejected. Theoretically.

Comment: Wibbly wobbly timey wimey stuff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR: You are correct - this appears to be an oversight by whoever put the montage together.**

The scene you are referring to - where Sisko is laying on the medtable and kisses Jake on the cheek - was during his second appearance to Jake in "[The Visitor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Visitor_(episode))". This event occurred during a timeline which no longer existed after the climax of the episode, and therefore would NOT be remembered by the Jake Sisko in the prime timeline of "[What You Leave Behind](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind_(episode))".

[image]

It was apparently [David Weddle](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/David_Weddle) and [Bradley Thompson](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bradley_Thompson) who put the montages together, and at the time they were instructed to find clips which highlighted the given character's relationships with other cast. Given that "The Visitor" was voted the 3rd best episode of the series, and that it's often cited as the best one to show the Sisko father/son relationship, it's most likely that the two chose a clip from the episode with those reasons... and never took into account the timeline scenario.

Comment: One can rationalize that Ben did remember the other timeline and *told* Jake about it, which serves as a proxy for a memory in the montage. I'll concede that it is a weak rationalization.

Comment: @Politank-Z I don't know that it is that weak. Just after Ben changes the timeline in *The Visitor* his response to Jake seems to imply that he remembered what happened. That he might tell Jake about it off screen isn't too unreasonable of an assumption.

Comment: That he would tell Jake about it in such detail that Jake visualized that scene in particular seems far fetched. It doesn't seem like a key part of the story.

Comment: @Xantec Only imply?  He was told to dodge and did so

Comment: There could have been an incident that DS9 didn't record, where they shared memories.